# Swapping Rows of 2D Array Inside a Struct Using a Pointer in C

Tags: c, arrays, memory, struct

I am trying to make a function to swap two rows from a 2D double array inside a struct using a pointer to that struct.

This is my function code so far.

```
void swap_rows(struct Double_Array* ptr , int r1 , int r2){

   double temp = ptr->array[r1];

   ptr->array[r1] = ptr->array[r2];

   ptr->array[r2] = temp;

}
```

These are the errors I am getting:

```
cannot convert 'double*' to 'double' in initialization  
invalid array assignment    
incompatible types in assignment of 'double' to 'double [9]'
```

The array is part of a struct which is allocated in memory. However I get errors when compiling.

Comment: You’re trying to do array assignment which isn’t a feature of C. You can’t do it that way.

Comment: Use `memcpy` or roll your own loop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First thing is you have to access a 2D array using its two indices like `array[0][r1]` and then swap `r1` and `r2` column by column in a loop like in [how do you swap two rows in a matrix (in C)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550475/how-do-you-swap-two-rows-in-a-matrix-in-c)

Comment: Thank you, I have changed my code to use a loop and I am getting my desired output. Although, I believe there should be a way to do this without the use of loops. I should have clarified in my original post but this is what I am interested in doing.

Comment: Vote to close as a duplicate instead of referring to another question.